# How can I get audio when playing a video in slow motion in Quicktime X?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, quicktime

In Quicktime X, I can slow down a video by holding down the right arrow. But when I do that, there isn't any audio. Is it possible to get audio?

Answer (score 1):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html) can do it, cmd and - or + for faster and slower video with sound affected.